# Two divs in a row. left one grows to available space when right one changes size

Tags: html, css

I want to achieve an effect that will appear as the left div is growing to accommodate the available space after the right div changes size.

I've built an example of the html that I want to work with (divs are clickable):
http://jsbin.com/anaPIJe/3/edit?html,css,output

Best solution would modify the jsbin code to make it work the way I intend.

Thanks!

*UPDATE* My Fault, I didn't mention I want a CSS only solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try css3 flex box,

http://jsbin.com/anaPIJe/9/

```
#container {
   display: flex;
   ...

#one {
   flex: 1;
   ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
#container {
    display: table-row;
}
.inner {
    display:table-cell;
}
```

[Demo here.](http://jsbin.com/anaPIJe/4/watch?html,css,output)

Comment: In your demo, the yellow one doesn't change in size when the red one changes.

Comment: It doesn't for me. Which browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the CSS and JavaScript slightly to make it work.

You can view the new code here: [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/anaPIJe/16/edit?css,js,output)

I've substracted 2 of each width because of an invisible borders that is being placed around the divs

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to mention i want a CSS only solution. my bad.